# Assign text to a variable and then use in next screen?

Tags: cypress

I have a Test Case where I wish to perform a Submit on one screen and then a popup is shown with a reference.
Then the Test Case goes a Search page and the idea is to a search using the reference.
What I seem to having an issue is adding that reference to a variable and then use it on the search page

```
// assign reference to Alias
cy.get('#referane_name').invoke('text').as('reference')

// few steps to return to search page
cy.get('#search_field').type('@reference')
```

I have tried adding the second part into a .then and then get an error on the get

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way aliases work - please refer to the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as)

```js
cy.get('#reference_name')
  .invoke('text')
  .as('reference')

... later 

cy.get('@reference').then(reference => {
  cy.get('#search_field').type(reference)
})
```